# Converting a .gif into Separate Frames with Ruby

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rmagick

I was thinking about using Rmagick, does anyone else have a good exp with this program? I have seen some Java scripts that do this but I'm more use to working in Ruby.

Comment: Yes, it is able to split .gif into separate images.

Answer (score 3):

*RMagick* gem is able to split .gif into separate images. See [`::read` method](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image1.html#read). It returns:

> An array containing 0 or more Image objects. If the file is a multi-image file such as an animated GIF or a Photoshop PSD file with multiple layers, the array contains an Image object for each image or layer in the file.

Do something like this:

```
image = Image.read( 'file.gif' )
```